Why do we have to go beyond Peano to prove Goodstein
I have recently learned that Peano arithmetics is not enough to prove the Goodstein's theorem, which came to me as surprise since everything that happens in Goodstein's theorem is finite. Perhaps this implies my poor understanding of Peano arithmetics and its nature, so what are the conceptual reasons why PA is not strong enough for such "finite" statements as Goodstein's?

The paper by Kirby and Paris linked to by the Wikipedia page you link to provides a proof. How does that fail to answer your question?

My question is what's a conceptual explanation why PA is not strong enough for Goodstein, not how to prove it @PaulTanenbaum

But in what way does their proof fail to answer your question? Clarifying that could help inspire answers that do get at what you’re after.

Do you have an intuitive idea behind the the proof of Goodstein's theorem?  Something like if the first infinite ordinal $\omega$ is an upper bound on something then, when you subtract $1$, you must be left with some finite ordinal number from which you can then subtract a finite number of $1$s to reach $0$, and that something similar happens with more complicated normal forms.  It is then at least plausible that translating this kind of argument into something which does not use infinite ordinals may be difficult or indeed impossible.

@Henry I don't, actually. I think it may be just a very good example of where intuitive math fails: even though the problem looks "finite", PA is not strong enough for its proof

There is a detailed discussion of this here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/474433/heuristic-interpretations-of-the-pa-unprovability-of-goodsteins-theorem

The key reason is that $PA$ is unable to prove primitive recursive transfinite induction for $\varepsilon_0=\sup\{\omega,\omega^{\omega},\omega^{\omega^{\omega}}\dots,\}$. This is due to Gentzen (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gentzen's_consistency_proof), who showed that the consistency of Peano is provable over some weak fragment of arithmetic and  primitive recursive transfinite induction for some reasonable representation of $\varepsilon_0$. In "Goodstein's theorem revisited" Rathjen points out that it seems Goodstein formulated his theorem to in a sense capture the well orderability of $\varepsilon_0$. Unfortunately, being a well order is a $\Pi^1_1$ statement, that is it makes use of a universal set quantifier, so it cannot be formalized in the first order language of $PA$. But what is needed for Gentzen's proof is that $\varepsilon_0$ does not have any infinite descending primitive recursive sequences, this statement is first order and can be formalized in the language of $PA$. In the same paper, Rathjen shows that over $\textbf{RCA}_0$ (a weak second order fragment of arithmetic), the well ordering of $\varepsilon_0$ is equivalent to all Goodstein sequences terminate, and over $PA$ primitive recursive well ordering of $\varepsilon_0$ is equivalent to all primitive recursive Goodstein sequences terminate.
Edit: the preprint to Rathjen's paper can be found at: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1405.4484
and the published version can be be found at: https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-319-10103-3_9.

Note that the paper was published as  Rathjen, Michael.  Goodstein's theorem revisited. Gentzen's centenary, 229–242, Springer, Cham, 2015.

Not only that, we may think of Goodstein sequence as an finitary approximation of an infinite descending sequence over $\varepsilon_0$, obtained from a given Cantor normal form with every coefficient is either 0 or 1 by replacing $\omega$ with 2, then increase the base number as the sequence proceeds. I believe it is why Goodstein proposed his sequence and conjectured its termination is stronger than PA (Goodstein himself did not prove it, although he hinted his sequence is tied with Gentzen's result.)
